# Realizar uma busca em tabela relacionada no Laravel e paginar

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Gostaria de Pesquisar todas as pessoas de determinada turma baseada no codigo da turma usando Laravel:
[image: Relacionamento]

E logo depois paginar, para fazer uma lista.

Aluno

```
public function turmas()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Turma::class,'turma_classe', 'turma_id','aluno_id');
}
```

Turma

```
public function alunos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Aluno::class,'turma_classe', 'aluno_id','turma_id');
}
```

Busca

```
$aluno = Aluno::find(1);
$turmas = $aluno->turmas;

foreach($turmas as $turma)
{
    var_dump(Aluno::with(Turma::class)->where('codigo', $turma->codigo));
}
```

Comment: Você está usando algum código? e/ou está usando `Model`? se sim tem como disponibilizar na pergunta!

Comment: A pergunta correta é: Pesquisar todas os `Alunos` de um determinada `Turma`? é isso?

Comment: vou atualizar a pergunta

Comment: Sim, usando o código da `Turma`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você já tem a relação pronta nos *models*, é só usar a propriedade de navegação `alunos` no model `Turma`.

```
$turma = Turma::where('codigo', $codigoTurma)->first();

$alunos = $turma->alunos;
```

Pra paginar você pode usar o método `paginate` do Laravel, tem quase tudo o que é necessário pra se fazer uma paginação nele.

```
$registros = $alunos->paginate();
```

[Veja mais na documentação do Laravel.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination)

Comment: Consigo realizar o `Turma:find($idTurma)` utilizando uma outra coluna da tabela, no caso `codigo`?

Comment: @ALE_ROM Editei a resposta